# Xcode storyboard in new ios project templates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Xcode and Objective-c. I have the latest Xcode version, but when I create a new  IOS project, regardless of the version, the generated code does not use auto property synthesis or storyboards, although I found some tutorials that says that it should use them by default. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: What template are you choosing to start a new project?

Comment: What do you mean does not use? When you create a new project, it asks if you want to use storyboards. If you do not check the checkbox, it won't use storyboards. Also, do you see in the code `@synthesize`? If not, then it is using auto synthesis.

Comment: @redelmar I was using empty project template, but it looks like with a master detail template I get a storyboard, however I still have synthesize declarations.

Comment: @Leo Natan can't find any use storyboard checkbox when I'm creating a new project. I do have synthsize declarations

Comment: @Jelly Look at this image: http://codewithchris.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/img/XCode_new_project_use_storyboards.jpg

Comment: @Leo Natan [Screenshot](http://imgbox.com/2NrMefsR) that is how mine look like

Comment: @LeoNatan, what version are you using? That checkbox isn't there any more in Xcode 5.1. You automatically get a storyboard based app unless you choose the empty template.

Comment: Thank you guys, I solved the storyboard mistery, what about synthesize?

Comment: @rdelmar Just a screenshot from the internets :-)

Comment: What do you mean about the synthesize? You are seeing @synthesize declarations? Where?

Comment: @rdelmar I have 3 synthesize declarations in AppDelegate.m when I create a new empty application

Comment: Hmm... I don't see those when I start a project from the empty template using Xcode 5.1. What objects are the three for?

Comment: @rdelmar I guess I'll just delete them

Comment: Can you post an image of those. I don't think I've ever seen them in any version of Xcode, so I'm curious as to what they are.

Comment: @rdelmar sure, here they are: [synthesize](http://imgbox.com/SG6zStW6)

Comment: I get them only for empty application template, single view template looks exactly like what I was looking for, not synthesize and a storyboard is created by default

Comment: Oh, ok, that's because you chose to use core data, I forgot about that one. They are there because they've overridden the getters for those properties (which are read only), so it's still necessary to use @synthesize in that circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to select a single view application from the list of template projects you are shown when you start a new project.

To do if from scratch you need to create a new storyboard and add the name of that storyboard to the Info Plist. See the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I guess that's what I'm going to do, but since I'm learning I'll have to create many new projects so it would have been helpful to have everything set up right by default.

Comment: @Jelly, just don't start with the empty template. Use the single view, tabbed, page based, or master detail templates, depending on what you want. All of those will give you a storyboard with some default controllers.